# TypeError: Object of type bool_ is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to write a dictionary to a json file with one of the values in boolean format. I get the following error when I am trying to run my code.

> raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
>   TypeError: Object of type bool_ is not JSON serializable

I am currently using Python for this purpose.

Comment: Could you please add the code segment to your question that causes this error? Thanks!

Comment: If you could edit your question and add the code. 

My guesses are there is a missed `"` somewhere. Or you are trying to convert a boolean. A json must be ```{"this":"that"}```

Comment: In  Python 2 the error message is "TypeError: True is not JSON serializable", which can be confusing.

Answer (score 43):

It's likely because of this issue (or something similar):

```
import numpy as np
import json

json.dumps({"X": np.int32(5) > 5})
```

> TypeError: Object of type 'bool_' is not JSON serializable

The issue is that you end up with something of type `bool_` instead of `bool`.

Calling `bool()`on whichever value(s) are of the wrong type will fix your issue (assuming your version of `bool_` behaves similarly to numpy's):

```
json.dumps({"X": bool(np.int32(5) > 5)})
```

> '{"X": false}'

Answer (score 19):

If you have multiple `bool_` keys or a nested structure, this will **convert all `bool_` fields including deeply nested** values, if any:

```
import json

class CustomJSONizer(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        return super().encode(bool(obj)) \
            if isinstance(obj, np.bool_) \
            else super().default(obj)
```

Then to convert the object/dict:

```
json.dumps(d, cls=CustomJSONizer)
```

Comment: This really should be the acceptable answer.  Chances are if you have one bool_ you have others.. plus all those other numpy types

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default for json:

```
print (json.dumps(mydict, indent=2, default=str))
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by converting the list from _bool type to bool type like this:

```
bool_list = np.array(bool_list, dtype=bool).tolist()
```

now calling:

```
json.dumps(bool_list)
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pandas dataframe and writing its values into a json file, you can do this:

```
bool(df['col_name_with_bool_values'].iat[0])
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the method `iat` does?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Convert the bool value to a string - dict["your_key"] = str(bool value)

Comment: This would break the internal json conversion from `True` to `true` and would make it hard to parse the json file back